# Radeon RX 560x graphics card doesn't have a driver for Ubuntu

Tags: gdm

Hi I have bought a new laptop Asus tuf .
Below is config for same
ASUS TUF FX505DY-BQ002T 15.6-inch FHD Gaming Laptop (AMD Ryzen 5-3550H/8GB/1TB HDD/Windows 10/Radeon RX 560X 4GB Graphics/2.20 Kg),

After dual boot when I choose Ubuntu 16.04 and tried login, Ubuntu freezes and doesn't show login screen.
When I set nomodeset in grub I am able to see login screen but display resolution is 800*600

I tried installing graphics card from Raedon's website but I see only windows driver for RX 560x.

Please help me as I am unable to find any solution from last 2 weeks.

I have tried Ubuntu xubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 but none of them work.

Please note I am ready to use basic graphics card if it solves my problem.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly we can do for you. It is up to AMD to release a driver for the card, and I hope they will do it sooner rather then later. Meanwhile, all you can do is wait.

Comment: Hi Mike is there anything available from Ubuntu for time being

Comment: I am struggling with this from past 2 weeks
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Ubuntu has the default driver called AMDGPU, the one with freezes and the 800x600 resolution, ...but you already know that. You could also try Ubuntu 19.04, to be released on April 18. It's newer, and might work better for you.

Comment: Hey Mike thanks for this. Is it possible to disable graphics card ? I am fine with that as well as long as Ubuntu works

Comment: It is sometimes possible to disable a GPU in the BIOS, however, the outcome will be a black screen with no signal. I doubt a desktop OS will be very useful then.

Comment: Hi @mike could it be problem because I have installed Ubuntu in uefi mode. I see even wifi driver is missing

Comment: What does "uefi mode" has to do with graphics or wifi?

Comment: When I try installing the driver for wifi a pop-up comes saying  in uefi mode third party packages doesn't install

Comment: @Sandeep That's because you have Secure Boot enabled, it's not due to UEFI. Always install UEFI machines in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 1):

So there are 2 problems that you must be facing. 
1.) Wifi Not Working(adapter not found) 2.) Graphic Drivers not working.(bcoz AMD drivers are not installed)

**DO ALL THIS while booting using NOMODESET**

The first one requires you to install the wifi drivers. The current Tuf laptop you are using has Realtek 8821CE whose drivers are yet not officially released by Ubuntu.To tackle this follow steps in the given link
[How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04). You will have to connect your laptop with a wired connection for this.

After Wifi Problem is fixed you will have to install the necessary graphics driver for your particular system specification from here https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-560.

Also follow the advice given on this link [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS R9 390X amdgpu guide / testing summary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094443/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-r9-390x-amdgpu-guide-testing-summary)

Comment: I have RX 560X and they don't have any driver available for that.

Comment: I have the same system as yours and the display problem is fixed too

Comment: added one more link this should solve your display problems

Comment: Hey Sanchit, Thanks for help. I will need sometime to do this. once i do i will let you know.

Comment: Hey @sanchit i downloaded the package from link you gave. I ran `./amdgpu-install -y` and got error in the end amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel

Comment: BTW wifi issue is resolved thanks for that, if you could please guide me with this, i will be greatful to you

Comment: I have ubuntu 18.04.2 and after installing amd-gpu graphic driver from link given by you I ran `./amdgpu-pro-install -y` and I was able to successfully install the driver after that i followed the link provided by you and still i get random errors. It will be great if you could let me kmow what all steps you followed. Also Please note i am dual booting windows with ubuntu. I am not able to go pass startup screen

Comment: @Sandeep I had same systems but other manufactures mine was Acer Nitro 5, just don't install the drivers it is not necessary, you will get most of it even you don't had the drivers. I was able to play warframe too.

Comment: @mandaputtra yes you are right. I installed ubuntu 19.04 and all started working except wifi for which i had to install a package