# Ubuntu installation on Asus tuf fx505dy

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro, amd-ryzen

I am unable to run any Ubuntu version on my Asus FX 505dy which I try to dual boot alongside windows 10. 
System configuration

ASUS TUF FX505DY-BQ002T 15.6-inch FHD Gaming Laptop (AMD Ryzen 5-3550H/8GB/1TB HDD/Windows 10/Radeon RX 560X 4GB Graphics/2.20 Kg),

Followed below link but it did not help
https://askubuntu.com/a/1094450/944534

I have tried installing 16.04, 18.04.1 18.04.2, Manjaro
Nothing worked. I am always stuck at boot loader after installing amdgpu driver from their official website and installing it using 'amdgpu-pro-install -y'

Comment: Try 19.04. The new kernel has been reported as working in the very same answers you linked.

Comment: And also disable Secure Boot, as commented in your other question.

Comment: Finally, Manjaro is off-topic. Regarding Ubuntu, for newer hardware always use the latest release. The latest LTS will catch up eventually, if the hardware enablement stack is installed, but for newbies, just install the latest release and upgrade when necessary.

Comment: Hi @GabrielaGarcia I will try it tonight and let you know.

Comment: @Gabriela thanks a ton for this suggestion. It worked as when I installed Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone ends up here like I did 2 days ago - I got the ASUS TUF FX505DY with a 256 SSD drive, and for some reason it would not get past the splash screen.

I found my answer in this thread: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/live-usb-boot-stops-at-lvm2-mirror-monitoring-on-ryzen-5-vega-8-notebook/77343

I had to add this kernel parameter:

```
nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500
```

Without it, the netbook would freeze about 30s into the boot, 100% of the time. Don't forget to add the above kernel parameter to `grub.cfg` as well, otherwise it will freeze after install.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever faces this issue please try to install Ubuntu 19.04. it worked for me

Comment: The problem of WiFi driver being unassigned still persisted for my model FX505. I am trying HWE kernel updation now.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04

try this. also please disable secure boot before you do this