# Cannot get amdgpu work on ubuntu 18.04 and cinnamon 3.6.7. What should I do?

Tags: 18.04, cinnamon, amdgpu, vulkan

Driver In use :

```
   gediz@gg-Desk:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

modules:

```
gediz@gg-Desk:~$ lsmod |grep radeon
radeon               1449984  23
ttm                   102400  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm_kms_helper        180224  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm                   483328  10 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon,ttm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,ra
```

OS :

```
Linux gg-Desk 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 10:36:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Desktop Environment:

```
gediz@gg-Desk:~$ cinnamon --version
Cinnamon 3.6.7
```

What I have tried is to follow this guide : 
[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS R9 390X amdgpu guide / testing summary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094443/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-r9-390x-amdgpu-guide-testing-summary). And tired to login cinnamon , it runs on cpu cannot find hardware acceleration. Ubuntu Unity (or wayland) and gnome-session-flashback are also run on cpu.

dpkg info of amdgpu:

```
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                       2.4.100+git1910260630.0a7ad7~oibaf~b         amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386                        2.4.100+git1910260630.0a7ad7~oibaf~b         i386         Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04        19.0.1-1~18.04.1                             amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
```

dpkg info of vulkan:

```
ii  libvulkan1:amd64                           1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1                amd64        Vulkan loader library
ii  libvulkan1:i386                            1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1                i386         Vulkan loader library
ii  mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64                  19.3~git1910270730.a0c003~oibaf~b            amd64        Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
ii  mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386                   19.3~git1910270730.a0c003~oibaf~b            i386         Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
ii  vulkan-utils
```

I don't understand what is wrong. These are the default packages wich comes with ubuntu 18.04. I did not install any additional package other than mesa vulkan drivers. Should I ?

I also have a bonus question. Display goes off and on again spontaneously. I wanted to find a log about gpu driver crashes but could not understand where to look. I searched in /var/log and also looked inside /proc cannot find any stream of card functioning ?

I found this :

```
gediz@gg-Desk:/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/subsystem/card0/device$ cat device
0x67b1
gediz@gg-Desk:/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/subsystem/card0/device$ cat current_link_width 
16
gediz@gg-Desk:/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/subsystem/card0/device$ cat current_link_speed
8 GT/s
gediz@gg-Desk:/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/subsystem/card0/device$ cat driver_override 
(null)
```

And situation replicates and screen goes off and on when I do :

```
xrandr -q
```

btw edid information is :

```
gediz@gg-Desk:/sys/class/drm/card0/card0-DP-1$ xxd /sys/class/drm/card0/card0-DP-1/edid
00000000: 00ff ffff ffff ff00 10ac 57a0 4c45 4d30  ..........W.LEM0
00000010: 2f15 0104 b53c 2278 3a8e 05ad 4f33 b026  /....<"x:...O3.&
00000020: 0d50 54a5 4b00 8100 b300 d100 714f a940  .PT.K.......qO.@
00000030: 8180 0101 0101 565e 00a0 a0a0 2950 3020  ......V^....)P0 
00000040: 3500 5550 2100 001a 0000 00ff 0047 3630  5.UP!........G60
00000050: 3654 3142 4930 4d45 4c0a 0000 00fc 0044  6T1BI0MEL......D
00000060: 454c 4c20 5532 3731 310a 2020 0000 00fd  ELL U2711.  ....
00000070: 0031 561d 711e 000a 2020 2020 2020 012d  .1V.q...      .-
00000080: 0203 1df1 5090 0504 0302 0716 0106 1112  ....P...........
00000090: 1513 141f 2023 0d7f 0783 0f00 0002 3a80  .... #........:.
000000a0: 1871 382d 4058 2c25 0055 5021 0000 1e01  .q8-@X,%.UP!....
000000b0: 1d80 1871 1c16 2058 2c25 0055 5021 0000  ...q.. X,%.UP!..
000000c0: 9e01 1d00 7251 d01e 206e 2855 0055 5021  ....rQ.. n(U.UP!
000000d0: 0000 1e8c 0ad0 8a20 e02d 1010 3e96 0055  ....... .-..>..U
000000e0: 5021 0000 1800 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  P!..............
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 004b  ...............K
```

Could you help me a little ?.You can also direct me to a guide to understand how to monitor linux kernel and driver activities closely and how dkms,dri,modules of gpu work in conjunction with Xorg.

I dont mind reading and struggling with things for long hours. A quick solution would also be appriciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem: 
I forgot to update initramfs after removing amdgpu.dpm parameter.

Second problem is that Monitor has defective capacitive button which activates randomly ... Also has 19 - 20 pin dipsplay port conflict problem Dell U2711. They have deigned 3.3v at both sink and source to power up some DVI - ethernet ->> Displayport converter chips on cable. Monitor is feeding back power to case. We have cut down the 20.pin's cable

And all things are working now.